# System.InvalidOperationException when managing a dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, button, parent-child, invalidoperationexception

I have encountered an error called System.InvalidOperationException.

Additional information: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

I have searched through internet for the solutions but none of them solve my problem.

I created a button called "Open Dialog", to open a dialog. After I opened the dialog, there are two buttons showed in the dialog, "Save" and "Cancel". The function of "Cancel" is to close the dialog. However, after I clicked "Cancel", when I tried to reopen the dialog again by clicking the "Open Dialog", I have encountered the error stated above.

I will post my codes here as well for the event handling method.

In the class of MainWindow:

```
private void openDialogButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PersonIDTable.ShowDialog();
        }
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public void ShowDialog()
        {
            PersonID.UserControls.PersonIDDialog dialog = new PersonID.UserControls.PersonIDDialog (this);
            dialog.Show();
        }
```

In the class of Dialog:

```
private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Do you guys have any idea to solve the problem? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `PersonIDTable` is your `ViewModel` class?

Comment: yup, PersonIDTable is my ViewModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much told the answer in your question, you closed the dialog so you can't reopen it.
Insert the creation of `PersonIDTable` inside `openDialogButton_Click`, that should fix it.

Example:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Would have told you this through the comment, but I don't have enough reputation.